# Openlayers simplify linestring on the fly

Tags: openlayers-2

I have an issue on my OpenLayers openstreetmaps where I am loading LineString features from a kml file. Everything works fine except performance due to the sheer complexity of the LineString and the number of linestrings. I wanted to use the simplyfy() function to simplify the linestring geometry/feature. Here is some code I wrote to simplify on the fly. The problem is in the line of code below:

```
            feature.geometry.components[i].simplify(0.1);
```

This does not seem to modify the original geometry feature components at all. What am I doing wrong? I think we might need to use removeComponents and then add the simplified geometries using addComponents() but how to do this?

```
preFeatureInsert: function(feature)

{
    if (feature != "undefined" && feature.geometry != "undefined" && feature.geometry.CLASS_NAME == "OpenLayers.Geometry.Collection");
    {
        if (feature.geometry.components != "undefined" && typeof(feature.geometry.components) != "undefined")
        {
            for (var i = 0; i < feature.geometry.components.length; i++)
            {
                if (feature.geometry.components[i].CLASS_NAME ==  "OpenLayers.Geometry.LineString")
                {
                    feature.geometry.components[i].simplify(0.1);
                }
            }
        }                           
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

According to [the docs](http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Geometry/LineString-js.html#OpenLayers.Geometry.LineString.simplify) the simplify function returns the simplified linestring (it doesn't modify the original). Therefore I believe you should be using

```
feature.geometry.components[i] = feature.geometry.components[i].simplify(0.1);
```

If feasible it would be far prefereable to generalise the feature once at the data-level rather than every time it is loaded on the client.